# SQL Server Stored Procedure Return Value Based on Query Success

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014, I have created a simple stored procedure which does a bulk insert; what I'm struggling with is capturing if the bulk insert succeed or failed and returning 0 or 1 respectively.

The stored procedure code is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkInsert] 
    @file_name nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @bulk_insert NVARCHAR(2000);

    SET @bulk_insert  = 
    N'BULK INSERT log_door_access FROM ''' +
    @file_name +
    N''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0A'');';

    EXEC sp_executesql @bulk_insert;
END
```

I'm trying to capture the `EXEC` result and return a 1 if all went well and 0 if an error occurred.

Comment: (`TRY...CATCH`)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175976.aspx] - _'Implements error handling for Transact-SQL that is similar to the exception handling in the Microsoft Visual C#...'_

Comment: @Serg I have just tried that and it works.  If you post it as an answer I will accept it as such.

Comment: This is trivial answer and I'm sure it should be formatted as answer but I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [`TRY...CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175976.aspx) - *'Implements error handling for Transact-SQL that is similar to the exception handling in the Microsoft Visual C#...'*

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkInsert] 
@file_name nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @bulk_insert NVARCHAR(2000);

    SET @bulk_insert  = 
    N'BULK INSERT log_door_access FROM ''' +
    @file_name +
    N''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0A'');';

    declare @r int
    EXEC @r = sp_executesql @bulk_insert;

    select @r
END
```

should do, or use an output parameter for sp_executesql, or a try catch block.

Comment: For some reason this approach always returns 0. Apparently bulk insert doesn't return anything therefore there is nothing to assign to the variable.